# загрузить изменения в github после ошибки аутентификации IntellijIdea

Tags: github, intelij

Сценарий такой.
1.В идее подключен репозиторий в гитхабе - все пушится нормально.
2.Вносим изменения в проект.
3.Удаляем токен.
4.Пушим и получаем ошибку:

```
22:24   Push failed
            Invocation failed Server returned invalid Response.
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Server returned invalid Response.
            at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.askUsername(GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:50)
            at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:64)
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned invalid Response.
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendRequest(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:242)
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:90)
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194)
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185)
            at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178)
            at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.askUsername(GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:47)
            ... 1 more
            remote: No anonymous write access.
            Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/...
```

5. Добавляем снова токен. Обновляем токен в идее.
6. Пробуем пушить - не получается все файлы обновлены.
7. Пробуем пулить - не получается все файлы соответствуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое - вносим изменения в любой файл (напр. просто поставить где-нибудь пробельчик) и пушим.
Все обновится.